# C++ Evil Hangman Implementation problems

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector, crash

I'm trying to implement a version of Evil Hangman where the game changes word depending on what is the most difficult to guess. However I'm getting an error and I just can't seem to spot it. It's probably something stupid but it feels like I've been staring at it for hours. I've narrowed it down to this via print statements before it crashes:

```
vector<string> newWords;
    bool inword=false;
    int place=0;
    cout<<"here 1";
    if(!remove){//remove true so only keep words that dont have letter in them.
        cout<<" in if(remove) \n";
        for(int i=0;i<wordsLeft.size();i++){
            cout<<" in first loop \n";
            for(int n=0;n<(wordsLeft[i].length())&&!inword;n++){
                cout<<"in second loop n: "<<n<<" i: "<<i<<" inword: "<<inword<<" length: "<<wordsLeft[i].length()<<endl;
                if(wordsLeft[i].at(n)==letter){
                    inword=true;
                }
            }
            if(!inword){//if false then add word meaning words not containing letter array
                    newWords[place]=wordsLeft[i];
                    place+=1;
            }
            else{
                inword=false;
            }
        }
        cout<<"here 2";
    }
    else{//remove false so only keep words that have letter in them.
        cout<<"here 3";
        for(int i=0;i<wordsLeft.size();i++){
            for(int n=0;n<(wordsLeft[i].length())&&!inword;n++){
                if(wordsLeft[i].at(n)==letter){
                    inword=true;
                }
            }
            if(inword){//if true then add word meaning words containing letter array
                    newWords[place]=wordsLeft[i];
                    place+=1;
                    inword=false;
            }
        }
        cout<<"here 3.5";
    }
    cout<<"here 4";
    index=place;
    wordsLeft=newWords;
}
```

Comment: "I'm getting an error" ... and that would be what exactly?

Comment: @Cyber it's saying that wordsLeft wasn't declared in the scope

Comment: Are you declaring `wordLeft` before before this snippet?  Because it isn't declared.  Also if `wordsLeft` and `newWords` are `std::vectors` you should use `std::vector<T>.iterator()` instead of integers.

Comment: Where did you place the declaration for "wordsLeft" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add comments yet, but based on your comment `it's saying that wordsLeft wasn't declared in the scope`, that means that `wordsLeft` in your first for loop is inaccessible. You may have definied that variable elsewhere in another function or it may be private.

Post where wordsLeft was definied and for next time: **Post the error message/code**